# Error while reading data from csv file using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, yahoo-finance, read.csv

```py
import yfinance as yahooFinance
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd

ticker = 'TSLA'

period1 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 1, 23, 59).timetuple()))  # year,month,date
period2 = int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime(2022, 12, 31, 23, 59).timetuple()))  # year,month,date
interval = '1wk'  # time interval
query_string = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1={period1}&period2={period2}&interval={interval}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'
df = pd.read_csv(f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1={period1}&period2={period2}&interval={interval}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true')
print(df)
```

The above is my code
when I run it , the following error comes

```
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\util\_decorators.py", line 311, in wrapper      
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 680, in read_csv   
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 575, in _read      
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 933, in __init__   
    self._engine = self._make_engine(f, self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers\readers.py", line 1217, in _make_engine
    self.handles = get_handle(  # type: ignore[call-overload]
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 670, in get_handle
    ioargs = _get_filepath_or_buffer(
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 339, in _get_filepath_or_buffer
    with urlopen(req_info) as req:
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\common.py", line 239, in urlopen
    return urllib.request.urlopen(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 214, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 523, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 632, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 561, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 494, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\BRBCO\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\urllib\request.py", line 641, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can anyone please tell me where  am I going wrong

Comment: You receive HTTP status code `400 Bad Request` which suggests that some of the parameters you pass in your URL are not correct/ correctly formatted etc. . Read the API documentation of the API you' re using to see what you are expected to provide.

Comment: Why do you save the url to the variable `query_string`, and then not use the variable in the next line? (I don't need to know, but you probably want to change that.) Then you can print the value of `query_string` before you make the request. If it fails, you can try taking what was printed out and putting it into a browser window; that will tell you if it's even a valid site. If it's not, then probably one of your variables is incorrect.

Answer (score 2):

Both `period1` and `period2` are invalid, as they lie in the future. Adjust them e. g. with `datetime.date(2021,4,5)` or `datetime.date.today()` to get the current date, which is the latest possible date.

```
import time
import datetime
import pandas as pd

ticker = 'TSLA'

period1 = int(time.mktime(datetime.date(2021,4,5).timetuple()))
period2 = int(time.mktime(datetime.date.today().timetuple())) 
interval = '1wk'

query_string = f'https://query1.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/download/{ticker}?period1={period1}&period2={period2}&interval={interval}&events=history&includeAdjustedClose=true'

df = pd.read_csv(query_string)
```

Comment: Yup Thank you so much I got the correct output now